# Display callable attribute from related model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have next models:

```python
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    def admin_link(self):
        url = reverse(
            'admin:%s_%s_change' % (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name), args=(self.pk, )
        )

        return '<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'.format(
            url=url, id=str(self)
        )
    admin_link.allow_tags = True
    admin_link.short_description = _('Admin Link')

 class Account(BaseModel):
     pass

 class Order(BaseModel):
     account = models.ForeignKey(
         'base.Account', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='orders',
         verbose_name=_('Account'), null=False
     )
```

And I created admin model for `Order` model:

```python
class OrderAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (_('Order'), {'fields': [
            'account__admin_link', 
        ]})
    ]
```

When I go to order change page, I getiing error:

> FieldError at /admin/base/order/1475d5d6-135f-454e-bec4-a801183dfc5f/change/
>   Unknown field(s) (account__admin_link) specified for Order. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class OrderAdmin.

I don't want write many identical functions in different admin models (I have many relations with Account model).

Can i use one function but display it in fields and fields sets?